# Flask-WTF - validate_on_submit() is never executed

Tags: python, forms, validation, flask, wtforms

I'm using Flask-WTF:

Here is my form:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form, TextField

class BookNewForm(Form):
    name = TextField('Name')
```

Here is the controller:

```
@book.route('/book/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def customers_new():
    form = BookNewForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        print "submitted"
    if form.validate():
        print "valid"
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Successfully created a new book")
        return redirect(url_for('.books_show'))
    return render_template('views/books_new.html', form=form)
```

Now the problem is, if you look at my print statements, it always prints submitted, but it NEVER prints valid and validate_on_submit() is never executed. Why?

Comment: Link for WTF validate. Compare two dates if start date is greater than end date then give error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53804438/9477847

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You're not inserting the CSRF field in the HTML form.

```
<form method=post>
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.name }}
    <input type=submit>
</form>
```

After adding `form.csrf_token` to the template ([docs](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#creating-forms)), the form will validate as expected.

Add `print(form.errors)` after validating the form to see the errors that were raised.  `errors` will be empty before validation.  In this case, there is an error about missing

```
@book.route('/book/new_no_csrf', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def customers_new_no_csrf():
    form = BookNewForm()
    print(form.errors)

    if form.is_submitted():
        print("submitted")

    if form.validate():
        print("valid")

    print(form.errors)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Successfully created a new book")
        return redirect(url_for('.books_show'))

    return render_template('books_new.html', form=form)
```

```
{}
submitted
{'csrf_token': [u'CSRF token missing']}
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2012 02:01:08] "POST /book/new_no_csrf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2012 02:01:08] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

[I created an example on GitHub.](https://github.com/ajford/Flask-wtf-SO-Question-10722968)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the exact problem! I didn't include the csrf field in my form. Trying to solve it with `{{ form.csrf }}` didn't work, but doing: `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` solved the problem! You were also right about the error printing, good to know how that works properly now!

Comment: Glad to help. If you're running WTForms 0.6 or later, `form.csrf` became `form.csrf_token` so watch out for that, but `form.hidden_tag()` works just as well.

Comment: This was giving me nightmare. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wonder why this critical part is missing from the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

you can print errors

```
print form.errors
```

or

```
app.logger.debug(form.errors)
```

and if you got csrf-error, you should set **form.csrf_token** in your template.

Comment: thanks for this hint, but 'print form.errors' prints {} . Still form.validate() returns False

Comment: I was wondering how one would go about debugging Flask form validation problems. Very good

Answer (score 4):

I came across this when trying to render a `FormField` being iterated over my `FieldList` in my template. I had to embed two hidden_tag elements one for the `FieldList` form and one for the `FieldForm` form, search the template comments for keyword "HIDDEN TAG"

```
class ParamRangeForm( FlaskForm ):
    minX = FloatField( )
    maxX = FloatField( )

class ParamRangesForm( FlaskForm ):
    paramRanges = FieldList( FormField( ParamRangeForm ) )
    submit      = SubmitField( 'Submit' )

    def loadParams( self ) :
        for paramName in ["p1" , "p2" , "p3", "p4"] :
            prf = ParamRangeForm( )
            prf.minX = -100.9#float('-inf')
            prf.maxX = 100.5#float('-inf')
            self.paramRanges.append_entry( prf )

...

  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ rangesForm.hidden_tag() }} <!--#### HIDDEN TAG #1 -->
    <table>
      <!--Print Column Headers-->
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="ColumnHeader">Parameter</td>
        <th class="ColumnHeader">Min</td>
        <th class="ColumnHeader">Max</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <!--Print Parameter Rows-->
      <tbody>
      {% for paramRange in rangesForm.paramRanges %}
        <tr>
          {{ paramRange.hidden_tag() }} <!--#### HIDDEN TAG #2 -->
          <td>p{{ loop.index }}</td>
          <td>{{ paramRange.minX }}</td>
          <td>{{ paramRange.maxX }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    {{ rangesForm.submit() }}
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

insert this  after the  tag in template html file:

```
 {{ form.csrf_token }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was clearing the flask session if I wasn't logged in before every request. This was causing this issue.

```
@main.before_request
def before_request():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated():
        # TODO clean sessions may cause CSRF missing issue
        session.clear()
        print "Session Cleared"
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the  API has changed.Maybe try changing

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
```

to:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a several hours debugging a validation issue with Flask-WTF. The issue like many others was a CSRF validation issue. However, mine was not caused by any of the common issues I have found.

The standard Flask-WTF implementation of CSRF requires **two** things be delivered to the browser.

**One:** The hidden CSRF form field e.g.

```
<input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="ImYzODdmZTdhYTRlMmNkYWRjYmRlYWFmZjQxMDllZTQ1OWZmYzg3MTki.XKvOPg.gUCkF9j-vg0PrL2PRH-v43GeHu0">
```

**Two:** The session cookie HTTP response header e.g.

```
Set-Cookie: session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiZjM4N2ZlN2FhNGUyY2RhZGNiZGVhYWZmNDEwOWVlNDU5ZmZjODcxOSJ9.XKvOPg.a3-W62MHvaGVkv2GYCi-dgpLE3Y; HttpOnly; Path=/
```

If either of these are missing the browser will fail to send the proper CSRF validation. Of course, this in turn causes the form validation to fail.

If the `csrf_token` hidden field is present in the form but the session cookie is missing, you will receive the following response when the form is submitted...

```
Bad Request
The CSRF session token is missing.
```

In my case the session cookie was missing because of a bug in my code. I needed to serve a custom HTTP header across the entire Flask site. I included it like this...

```
class LocalFlask(Flask):

    def process_response(self, response):
        response.headers['my-header'] = 'My Header Value'
        return response

app = LocalFlask(__name__)
```

This however causes anything that rellys on the the `Flask.response.headers` method to fail. One of those is Flaks-WTF setting the session cookie HTTP header.

This can be solved by adding the `super()` method to the `LocalFlask` class so that it inherits methods form the `Flask` class.

```
class LocalFlask(Flask):

    def process_response(self, response):
        response.headers['my-header'] = 'My Header Value'
        #LocalFlask inherits methods from Flask
        super(LocalFlask, self).process_response(response)
        return response

app = LocalFlask(__name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried all the solutions mentioned

```
form.hidden_tag()
form.csrf_token
form.csrf
```

with

```
app.secret_key=""
app.config["SECRET_KEY"]=""
```

but `form.validate_on_submit()` always returned false.

None of these seem to work for me, so I used the basic method and this method

```
import request
request.method="POST"
```

or

```
form.is_submitted()
```

These two worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `form.validate_on_submit()` and `form.validate()` always `return False` if I access the route via Simple Browser: Show command in vscode but return True if I use chrome

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem and solved it by adding {{ form.csfr_token }} in  tag :

```
<form method=post> 
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

Be careful about auto suggestion which may complete your expression by this :

{{ form._csrf_token }}

The above expression is similar to the correct one but will not work. By adding the right code (which is mentioned in "form tag" validation_on_submit() method will response the right result.