# Flask WTForms form does not validate

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I cannot get a certain simple Flask WTForm to validate.

After a couple of days of struggle, I've tried everything I can think of. I'm new to Flask and Web programming in general.

Here's a stripped-down but working version of my code. The only action of the test code (other than submitting the form) is to print messages to terminal. Its appearance when running:

[image: Screenshot of running code]

This is views.py:

```
    # -*- coding: utf_8 -*-
...

@app.route('/test/new/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def newTest():
    form = TestForm(request.form)
    if form:
        print 'request.form.get(\'name\') is %s' % (request.form.get('name'),)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'in newTest(), request is POST'
        if form.validate():
            print 'form validates'
            return redirect(url_for('allTests'))
        else:
            print 'form does not validate'
            return render_template('newTest.html', form=form)
    else:
        return render_template('newTest.html', form=form)
```

Here's forms.py:

```
class TestForm(Form):
    name = StringField(u"Test Name", [validators.InputRequired()])
    address = StringField(u"Test Address", [validators.InputRequired()])

    submit = SubmitField(u"Submit")
```

models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Unicode
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class TestModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'test'

    name = Column(Unicode(80), nullable = False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    address = Column(Unicode(80), nullable = False)
```

and the template:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="{{ url_for('newTest') }}" method="POST" name="add_rest">
        <ul>
            <li>Name: {{ form.name }}</li>
            <li>Address: {{ form.address }}</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Create"> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output (to terminal) I get when I click "Create" above:

```
request.form.get('name') is Vinnie
in newTest(), request is POST
form does not validate
10.0.2.2 - - [18/Feb/2016 02:34:51] "POST /test/new/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

then the browser redisplays the form and its contents.

I assume I'm missing something simple, but I haven't been able to figure this out for the life of me.

The structure of the code, as shown by "tree", is:

[image: code structure via tree]

I'd be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to insert a CSRF token in your HTML file?

For example, by adding the following to your Jinja template?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="{{ url_for('newTest') }}" method="POST" name="add_rest">
        <!-- Added line -->
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <ul>
            <li>Name: {{ form.name }}</li>
            <li>Address: {{ form.address }}</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Create"> 
    </div>
</body>
```

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722968/flask-wtf-validate-on-submit-is-never-executed) post may be useful.

You can also check the official documentation [here](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html) which indicates that the `validate()` function requires the use of a CSRF token.

Comment: Yesssss!!! Thanks so much! That (and a taking care of a couple of other errors I couldn't see because the validate() code was never executing) fixes it. This has been hanging me up for days.

Comment: @franklin, in my case, it still invalidates the form. I tried printing errors but there are no errors :/