# Flask importing SelectField choices from external file

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-wtforms

Creating a simple Student CRUD database I can't get the feature of 'Adding a Student' to work.  Currently it produces - "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable".

**EDIT : I figured out this is caused by using an external lookup table for 'SelectField' 'choices'.  The best answer that explains how to solve this by correctly breaking out the choices 'key, value' data into an external module will get marked as the answer. Thank you for your help. **

**My Form ...**

```
class AddStudent(FlaskForm):
    gender = SelectField('Gender :', choices=lookup.GENDER)
```

My lookup file 'lookup.py' ...

GENDER = [('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female')]

**Here is the Traceback ...**

```
builtins.TypeError
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
File "/Users/inyoka/Documents/dev/study/app/stud/views.py", line 16, in add
if form.validate_on_submit():
File "/Users/inyoka/Documents/dev/study/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 101, in validate_on_submit
return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
File "/Users/inyoka/Documents/dev/study/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 310, in validate
return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
File "/Users/inyoka/Documents/dev/study/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 152, in validate
if not field.validate(self, extra):
File "/Users/inyoka/Documents/dev/study/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 193, in validate
self.pre_validate(form)
File "/Users/inyoka/Documents/dev/study/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 468, in pre_validate
for v, _ in self.choices:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please post the error messasage with full stack trace.

Comment: I have added the traceback, I don't know how to get a full stack trace, but I am working on it.

Comment: Created a stripped down Git branch named ***"addsmall"*** to reduce the code needed to reproduce the error.  Made the initial introduction more concise as well.

Comment: It seems to be related to validation, I implemented the suggestions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722968/flask-wtf-validate-on-submit-is-never-executed  and the form is submitted, but not validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing values into the SelectField using 'choices=' the values needed to be produced by a generator.

For example in my form I would have ...

```
from .lookup import *

goal = SelectField('Professional Goal :', choices=Lookup(GOALS))
```

Would need to find the following in lookup.py ...

```
class Lookup:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items
    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.items:
            yield(item)

 # List of choices to yield
 GOALS = [('none', 'None'),
          ('TOEFL', 'TOEFL'),
          ('IELTS','IELTS'),
          ('iGCSE','iGCSE')]
```

This is worthwhile if you have a lot of choices to lookup.

For more information on generators I found this introduction ...

http://www.python-course.eu/generators.php

Answer (score -1):

In your view code, you create the form with `form = AddStudent()`. That gives you an empty student form. To fill the data in the form with the data from the request use `form = AddStudent(request.form)`. This will populate `form` with the data from your request.

Comment: @MennoHölscher I have refined my question, basically my lookup table for the SelectField 'choices' option doesn't work.