# Flask: Why is my view not rendering the template I want it to?

Tags: python, html, flask

Here is the class I created, model of the flask mega tutorial's [RegistrationForm](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins)

```
class eyeReaderInput(FlaskForm):
    article =  StringField('Article')
    submit = SubmitField('Enter')
```

And I've implemented that class in this view:

```
@app.route('/eyereader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def eyereader():

    form = eyeReaderInput()
    sTuple = ()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        string = wikipedia.page(form.article.data)
        for chunk in textwrap.wrap(string, 15):
            sTuple += (chunk,)

        return render_template('eyereader.html', string = sTuple, form = form)
    else:
        return render_template('eyereader.html', form = form)
```

with this being my template of `eyereader.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{% if string %}
<p><span>
    {% for s in string %}
    [{{s}}]<pre class="tab"></pre>
    {% endfor %}
</span></p>
{%  else %}

<p>Please input an article name</p>
<form action = "" method = "post">
    <p>{{ form.article.label}}<br>
       {{ form.article() }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>


</form>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm hoping to do is for the user to initially access the eyereader site using a 'GET' request (which is what happens when I look at my console), and once the user inserts the wikipedia article he wishes to read, it sends a 'POST' request with a new string parameter which will make `{% is string %}` true and instead show the wikipedia text.

However when I'm testing this, both 'GET' and 'POST' requests end up going to the input page. Does anyone know what I may be able to change to get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10722968/494134

Answer (score 0):

Option #1: Use two templates to handle the conditional content, tying each template to a different form action (GET/POST).

```
@app.route('/eyereader')
def show_template():
    return render_template("eyereader.html")
```

Option #2: Use JavaScript to dynamically populate content as needed.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#my_object').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $( "#my_object condition:true" ).text();
  if(selected == "yes") 
$(Do_Something_Here)
});
</script>
```