# Flask: miss some blocks

Tags: python, flask

I try to write simple service with flask but I have some problem. I try to render a template after submitting, but It doesn't go to some blocks

Main code

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main_page():
    main_form = Main_Submit_Form()
    text_form = Checking_Text_Form()
    image_form = Checking_Image_Form()

    if main_form.validate_on_submit():
        if main_form.name_checking.data:
            if text_form.validate_on_submit():
                request_name = str(text_form.checking_name.data)
                results = model.predict_name(request_name)
                return render_template('text_data.html', request_name=request_name, results=results)
            return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=text_form)
        if main_form.image_checking.data:
            if image_form.validate_on_submit():
                pass
    return render_template('main.html', form=main_form)
```

Main form looks like

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField

class Main_Submit_Form(FlaskForm):
    name_checking = SubmitField(label='Проверка Торгового наименования')
    image_checking = SubmitField(label='Проверка Логотипа')
```

Text form looks like

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, FileField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class Checking_Text_Form(FlaskForm):
    checking_name = StringField('Введите наименование компании', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit_text = SubmitField('Проверить')
```

Main html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Проверка товарного знака</h2>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p class="text">{{ form.name_checking() }}</p>
        <p class="image">{{ form.image_checking() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Login html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Проверка товарного знака</h2>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.checking_name.label }}<br>
            {{ form.checking_name(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit_text() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Textdata html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Результаты по запросу: {{ request_name }}</h2>
    {% for result in results %}
    <div><p>{{ result.company_name }}, сходство: <b>{{ result.cosine_sim }}</b></p></div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I can't go into block with checking `if text_from.validate_on_submit()` and I can't understand why.
How can I go into this block after rendering `login.html` template?
And is any way simplify this code? I don't think that it's a good example

Comment: Where is `text_from` in your code? EDIT nm, it's a typo, you mean `text_form`

Comment: @roganjosh I've thought that I should specify `text_form` in `Login html` instead `form`, but it's wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask-WTF - validate\_on\_submit() is never executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722968/flask-wtf-validate-on-submit-is-never-executed)