# I am unable to get data from flask forms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have like a search bar built with wtforms, but I don't know for some reason I am unable to fetch data or value entered in the search bar. I tried almost everything from online tutorials but just couldn't find the solution. Below is my code examples.

For my search bar, I have tried **form.search.data** and **request.form['search']** too but it's not working.

```
#flask_app.py

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request
from forms import SearchForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '791628bb0b13ce0c676dfde'

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
     return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/search', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.search.data == 'admin':
            return redirect(url_for('home'))

    return render_template('search.html', form= form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

#forms.py

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    search = StringField('search', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Search')

#search.html
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="" class="form-inline mt-4" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.search(class= 'form-control', placeholder= 'Enter term to search')}}
            {{form.submit(class= 'btn btn-outline-primary')}}
        </div>
    </form>
{%endblock%}

#home.html

{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Welcome to homepage!</h1>
{%endblock%}
```

Is there any bug? I expect **form.search.data** should be able to fetch data from search bar.

Comment: `action=""`... That doesn't submit anything to `search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not inserting the CSRF field in the HTML form which can be done via `form.hidden_tag()`

```
#search.html
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="" class="form-inline mt-4" method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.search(class='form-control', placeholder= 'Enter term to search')}}
            {{form.submit(class='btn btn-outline-primary')}}
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10793200/4711754)

Comment: I have same code as above and I did used your solution and I worked perfectly but why I couldn't get flashed data from search bar after                                                             `if form.validate_on_submit():                                                        
     flash(form.search.data)`

Comment: You need to add flashed messages to template via `get_flashed_messages()`. See the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/flashing/) here